# plot interaction terms in a mixed-model

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, interaction, mixed-models

I would like to visualize the effect of a significant interaction term in the following mixed effects model.

```
c1 <- lmer(log.weight ~ time + I(time^2) + temp + precip + time:precip + time:temp + (1|indiv), data = noctrl)
```

This model includes fixed effects of 'time' (simple and quadratic term), 'temperature', 'precipitation' and two interactions on the logarithmized response 'weight'. All terms are significant and the models assumptions of normality and homogeneity are met.

I’ve been using the 'effects' package to produce interaction plots to show the effect of the interactions. When I try to show the interaction of time and temperature (time:temp) with the following code I’m not sure whether the resulting plot correctly shows this interaction.

```
ef2 <- effect(term="time:temp", c1, multiline=TRUE)
y <- as.data.frame(ef2)
ggplot(y , aes(time, fit, color=temp)) + geom_point() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=fit-se, ymax=fit+se), width=0.4)
```

I need help understanding the [resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAlDm.pngv)  please. How come despite this interaction term is highly significant, the SEs overlap at each value of x? 
Am I using the effects package correctly? Or is it because I need to include the quadratic term of time I(time^2) in the interaction terms as well?

Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: I would fit `lmer(log.weight ~ poly(time, 2) * temp + poly(time, 2) * precip + (1|indiv), data = noctrl)`. It's not clear to me what it means to have only an interaction with the linear component. Your use of `effect` seems fine to me.

Comment: Thanks `@Axeman`. When I do model selection on `lmer(log.weight ~ time + I(time^2) + temp + precip + time:precip + time:temp + temp:precip + I(time^2):temp + I(time^2):precip + (1|indiv))` my best model still is `lmer(log.weight ~ time + I(time^2) + temp + precip + time:precip + time:temp + (1|indiv))`. Also, how is `lmer(log.weight ~ poly(time, 2) * temp + poly(time, 2) * precip + (1|indiv))` different from `lmer(log.weight ~ time + I(time^2) + temp + precip + I(time^2):temp + I(time^2):precip + (1|indiv))`. Thanks very much!

Comment: `lmer(log.weight ~ time + I(time^2) + temp + precip + I(time^2):temp + I(time^2):precip + (1|indiv))` only contains the interaction with the quadratic components. `poly(x, 2)` contains both the linear and quadratic component. See `?poly`.

Comment: I don't see why that's so surprising. But for statistical interpretation you'll have to go to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `@Axeman` It was because the poly model has two additional terms (interactions with the quadratic components). I don't understand why I need to include those interactions with quadratic components given they're not significant and don't improve model fit. Thanks very much for your help.